# How do I install windows back? :( Ubuntu is basically useless for me now, for some reason I can not do anything with it.

Tags: filesystem, data-corruption

I can't do anything on ubuntu anymore because of an error that says "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /" Everytime I choose to ignore it and still able to boot up, all my files are in read only mode, I can't open anything, or even copy to make a back up. I have a cd or USB that I can use to boot a windows 7 installation, but in the bios, it doesn't seem to read it. Please help!

Comment: Before you reinstall Windows, you can boot with a live Ubuntu USB to make a backup of your files, if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

All the files are in read-only mode because such are the default settings for Ubuntu in `/etc/fstab` file.

For instance, here is entry for my SSD:

```
UUID=xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime 0       1
```

Notice where it says `errors=remount-ro`, this reads as "if encountered errors on the hard drive, remount the drive in read only mode"

You can certainly mount the system with read write permissions in terminal with `sudo mount / -o remount,rw` and then edit `/etc/fstab`, however your bigger issue is the *errors on the hard drive* ! Big chance is that your hard drive is failing; this has nothing to do with Windows or Ubuntu - keep ignoring those errors and one day it will become un-bootable, at all, and then *hasta la vista , baby*.

I strongly suggest you backup your files and any important data, and get yourself a new hard drive